# How to resolve DLL Hell introduced since upgrading to EF Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, entity-framework-core

Our project (.Net Framework 4.6.2) was chugging along just fine on EF Core 1.1.0. Then we decided to upgrade to EF Core 2.0.0. Went through a few days of tweaking the code to use new syntax, getting our unit and integration tests to pass again, and finally they did. So today we deployed onto our QA site, which immediately broke with a DLL Hell message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

During the course of the upgrade I had updated System.Net.Http from 4.3.0 to 4.3.3, so I tried reversing that. Didn't help. I tried commenting out the dependent assembly reference in `web.config`, and that made the message change:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Hello! If I've understood correctly, that means that version 4.1.1.0 of System.Net.Http (which is the correct one) is actually being found by the binding redirect - but there's some other assembly that's coming along with my deployment, which is looking for version 4.0.0.0, and ignoring the binding redirect.

How do I find which assembly is messing me up? And how do I get it to respect the binding redirect?

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue but on the assemblyBinding tag there is an "appliesTo" attribute. If that is set to the wrong version the redirects will fail. We just removed the attribute when it started causing issues like this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/assemblybinding-element-for-runtime#attributes-and-elements

Comment: @asawyer I don't see any "appliesTo" tag in my `web.config`.

Comment: All I got sorry. Good luck.

Comment: When I upgraded one of my .NET Core apps to 2.0, I ran into DLL hell when I published the new build to Azure. This was because the previous versions of dependency DLLs weren't wiped out when publishing. If it's at all possible, put a hold on QA, shut down the application, wipe out the contents of the publish directory (except for any config or resources) and republish the application. I wrote about my troubles here: https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/11/02/deploying-a-net-core-2-0-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I'm not the only person to have been sucker-punched by this issue. See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22781).

**TLDR:** Visual Studio 2017 comes packed with a bunch of the latest and greatest DLLs, which are so very good, that MSBuild will impose them on you if you're working with .NET Framework 4.6.2 or earlier, because why would you want to use those cobwebby old versions that you specified in your binding redirects?

I've tried two solutions that worked:

1. **Quick & dirty:** Go into your `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461` folder. You'll find `lib` and `ref` folders there. Go into each of these and create a subfolder called `HideMe` or suchlike. Then move *all* the DLLs *except* `netstandard.dll` into the `HideMe` folder. Now MSBuild can't impose its ideas of which DLL is best for you.
2. **The proper way:** Upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7.1. That will be a little more labor-intensive and might break stuff, but at least you don't have to do hacks like my first workaround.